# SharedPreferences if statement for storing only one choice

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to Android development. I have recently been given a challenge that is basically a ViewPager with an array of images that you swipe between. Once you get to the image that fits you, you click on a button at the bottom to store your selection and move on to the next activity(The next activity has a back button that allows them to go back and choose another image if they want).

Since this is an offline challenge, I chose to use SharedPreferences as a way to store this selection.

My question is how can I go about storing this information one time and if the same image is selected a second time, nothing happens but if a new image is selected then it overwrites the previous one. I assume it involves an if...else statement but not quite sure how to set it up. Here is my current code inside of the onClick method for the button.

```
public void thatsMeClick(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PhysicalCondition.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.tabernaster.challengeone",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("motivator", viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    editor.apply();

    int myIntValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("motivator", -1);

    Log.i("motivator", Integer.toString(myIntValue));

}
```

Comment: Since SharedPreferences cannot contain duplicate keys, then your current setup correctly "does nothing" when you select the same image and "overwrites" when you select something else.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in needing an `if` statement. Basically you will check your current value using the same `int myIntValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("motivator", -1);` code you already have, however you will move that above your `editor.putInt` code. Like so:

```
int myIntValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("motivator", -1);
if(myIntValue != viewPager.getCurrentItem()){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("motivator", viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    editor.apply();
    myIntValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("motivator", -1);
}
```

However, since you are using the same key, this code is rather redundant. `SharedPreferences` will handle the overriding for you.

Comment: Yeah, the if-statement isn't really necessary

Comment: Thank you both for your responses, I really appreciate it!